# Regular Expression matching characters after a string

Tags: regex

**For the following expression**: `^swlang/(\d{2})/$`

matches a string `swlang` followed by two digit of integers.

Now to modify this expression so that it matches 2 characters instead.

I tried: `^swlang/(\S{2})/$` but it doesn't seem to work.

Note: I am trying to match a URL in django

the full code looks like this

```
url(r'^swlang/(\d{2})/$', 'klip.views.swlang'),
```

So for example, a url that is going to be routed to `klip.views.swlang`
would be `example.com/swlang/43`

The desired one may look like `example.com/swlang/en`

Comment: what are you trying to match?

Comment: and why do you have `/` before `(` and after `)` ? Did you try `^swlang(\S{2})$`

Comment: `/` will be matched using `\S`, so you dnt need those extra `/`s

Comment: Note that your regexp requires a slash at the end of string, and your examples miss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters are represented by a group like `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

```
\bswlang/([a-zA-Z0-9_]{2})/?
```

or you can use the predefined `\w`

```
\bswlang/(\w{2})/?$
```

the first option lets you define whatever character you exactly want the second only accepts letters, numbers and underscore.

After your EDIT I added the slashes, note the last one is `/?`. It means it may or may not be present in your url

If you use `\S` as pointed out by others , `example.swlang////` would match, if that's what you want fine, otherwise consider use one of my two suggestions.

Note: I changed the `^`(beginning of line) for `\b` (beginning of word) since your example included characters before 'slang'

Comment: `\w` is alpha-numeric character...which is not same as `char` .. technically speaking.

Comment: \S includes anything but spaces,tabs and newlines. It will work if that is what the OP wants, otherwise he/she should specify which characters are allowed.